# What are Sqoop's dependencies for?

Tags: hadoop, rdbms, sqoop

These are dependencies of Sqoop 1.4.2 (libs inside sqoop/lib):

```
ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
avro-1.5.3.jar
avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar
avro-mapred-1.5.3.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.3.jar
jopt-simple-3.2.jar
paranamer-2.3.jar
snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar
```

Why does Sqoop need to have all of them? (e.g. ant-eclipse - why? :) )

What do these dependencies actually do for sqoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like noone is willing to answer this question :)

So my opinion on Sqoop's dependencies is that it's just some magic bundle of jars that is enough to build Sqoop from sources and works with particular version of Hadoop that this bundle of Sqoop is supposed to work with.

Since Sqoop runs itself as

```
exec ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop "$@"
```

it means that both Hadoop and Sqoop jars with be in the CLASSPATH so dependencies can conflict depending on what is in Hadoop's CLASSPATH already.

Obviously

```
ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
```

are for building Sqoop.